# "Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)" fault

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an issue with my Android studio. Sometimes it works but when it doesn't it usually comes up with this error:

What should I do to fix the problem?
[image]

[image]
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wordpress.schoolworkhelpsite.swhsapp.MainActivity">

    <image>ic.launcher.png</image>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:text="SchoolWork HelpSite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
<xml>
```

If my code is wrong, what do I need to change?

Comment: Show the error, we don't read minds

Comment: your xml file has error and is unformatted make it correct may this resolves the error.

Comment: try to copy whole error log and post it, not the image

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio should immediately tell you what's wrong with the code. If not look for Lint in Settings and check every pertinent option.

1. `<image>ic.launcher.png</image>`

AS says

> Element image is not allowed here

If you want to use an image, use `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

2. `<xml>`

AS says:

> Multiple root tags

Why are you opening another root tag? Closing with `</xml>` would also be incorrect, where did you get that idea from? You just need to close the root tag, which in this case is the ConstraintLayout and your code is fine. Just delete that `<xml>` line.

Answer (score -1):

Error 1 : hope the screens are designed without any error, of so change the device and API versions in the preview palette you will get preview.

Error 2: Share your error which is shown in message tab. So that I will provide you rectification

Comment: I've changed the question now... hopefully this is better.